# Constrains on a child table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, sql-update

I have this situation:

```
MANAGER (ManagerID, Salary, .... , email)

PROJECT (ProjectID, ..., Date)
```

Since there is relationship M:N between Manager an project, I'll have a third table:

```
Manager_has_Project( ManagerID, ProjectID )
```

where **( ManagerID, ProjectID )**  is the compound PK for **Manager_has_Project**

Let's suppose we have to delete a Manager who has created some projects from our database: SQL won't make us do that. We could add the constraint on the fk ManagerID in the child table "ON DELETE CASCADE", but in this case we will lose information about, for example, how many managers worked for a project. The alternative is "ON DELETE SET NULL" but, since ManagerID is part of the compound pK of **Manager_has_Project**, we can't set a PK as null.

What would recommend to do?

Comment: Add a `STATUS` column to both the `MANAGER` and `MANAGER_HAS_PROJECT`. That column will tell you the validity of the relationship. You rarely delete data on a database, since "inactive data" is useful for auditing, reporting, etc. Typically you'll also add columns such as `VALID_FROM`, `VALID_UNTIL`, `CREATED_BY`, `UPDATED_BY`, etc. in order to have all details of **who** changed **what** and **when**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to to keep the information, use soft deletes rather than actually removing the rows.

That is, add a column, say `is_deleted` or `deletion_datetime` that indicates that a `Manager` has been deleted.  Then you can keep all the information, even about "deleted" managers.

You can use views so "normal" queries would only return managers who are not deleted.